# what is Boolean x'.y+x.y' equal to

Tags: math, boolean, simplification

i am stuck with a boolean expression help me solve what x.y'+x'.y =? 
i have exam today and i don't know how do solve this type. And in addition can someone recreate the boolean laws that involve two element instead of one for me? Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two inputs to the expression, so write out a truth table with the values of the inputs and for each term until you get the result.

```
x   y   x'  y'  x'.y    x.y'    x'.y+x.y'    
0   0   1   1   0       ...
0   1   1   0   1       ...
1   1   0   0   0       ...
1   0   0   1   0       ...
```

When you have done that, look for patterns in the last column. You should then recognise the pattern as being the same as a single operator.

The pattern for the inputs is usually a Gray code so that the output column reflects changes due to only one input changing, which usually can help show up the pattern.

Alternatively, when you have your result, plot it in a grid and spot the pattern that way, e.g. for x+y you'd get

```
x\y 0   1    
0   0   1
0   1   1
```